# C# application settings (user.config file) are persisting across versions when they shouldn't

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto, settings

I have an outlook addin that needs to save user-scoped settings.  I'm using the built-in settings capability of Visual Studio 2010 which saves a settings file (user.config) to an obscure location (in my case %AppData%\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\\12.0.6680.5000 )

It works fine except when I need to install a new version of my addin which has different values for some of the settings.  I change the default settings in the editor, then change the assembly and file versions and also the version of the .MSI (just for good measure) that installs my Outlook addin.  But when I uninstall and reinstall my addin, the addin keeps detecting the file located in the path above and does not create a new user.config with the new defaults.

I think the reason is because in the path to user.config above, the 12.0.6680.5000 version number does not refer to my Outlook addin, it refers to the version of Microsoft Outlook itself, which isn't going to change no matter what I do to my addin.

So how is the best way to handle this?  Should I just write a custom action for my setup project to delete the entire %AppData%\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\ folder during uninstall?

Comment: Why not create your own folder under local? Is there some specific reason to use the Microsoft folder?

Comment: You actually can't specify the path to user.config.  It's done for you automatically and I think it uses Microsoft and not my company because it's either due to the fact the addin runs in Microsoft Outlook or its a bug

Comment: Hmm. well in that case I would consider just deleting what was added as if the entire folder was deleted is there a possibility of having a negative impact on data that is not related to something else Microsoft needs that was just deleted by deleting the entire filder?